# Configuration of MAC IP core

Tags: ip, lattice-diamond

**How can we access configuration registers of Lattice Tri-Speed Ethernet MAC (TSMAC) IP Core in lattice diamond tool ?**

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: lattice diamond tool 3.7
device :- Lattice ECP3
I want access configuration registers of that IP core